# What could be the best approach to download the files from the web page using Selenium WebDriver with C#?

Tags: selenium

I am working on an application which has one module. The functionality of a module is to "opens the web page >> browse folders >> find links (.PDF/.XLSX/.DOC) and download the files on my local system".

I get stuck in this module. Can anybody tell me the best approach to accomplish the above task?

I am using selenium web driver with C# to develop the above application.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading with Selenium tends to be a quagmire, especially when dealing with cross-browser compatibility; going with JavaRobot, Sikuli, or FireFox only solutions all have their own issues

I'd suggest looking at using Selenium to get to the page with the files to download and figuring the links that way, then using WGet or similar to actually download the files.

SQA.StackExchange has couple good items [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver).  The two best options are the WGet method mentioned above, or write a download library in native code.